# Performance issue when uploading file to Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, iis, asp-classic, vb6, oracle11g

Please help me on this issue:

It is a file upload system(Classic ASP+ VB6 Com+): users upload txt file to Oracle DB. Now the issue is the system hangs when uploading data to some tables which contain some records (around 500,000 rows, about 40MB in size, not really big). If I truncate the table, the upload will be completed successfully.

The uploading logic: it reads the file, send 1000 records to server asynchonizely at a time and VB uses UPDATEBATCH to commit the inserting via ODBC. The problem is it only commits the first 1000 records. If the ASP time out setting in  IIS is default 90seconds, it will error out with ASP time out message. I increased the setting to a larger number (9000), then it hangs there after inserting first 1000 records.... . However, that only happens on PROD. I copied the table structure and data from PROD to DEV, then uploaded the same file, and it works fine on DEV.

Here is the table creation script:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TableA
(
  ID           NUMBER(12)               NOT NULL,
  ColA         NUMBER(12)               NOT NULL,
  ColB         NUMBER(5)                NOT NULL, 
  ColC         CHAR(2 BYTE), 
  ColD         VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE)
  ....
)
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   25
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          24K
            NEXT             1M
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
            FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
            CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING;
```

really appreciate for any suggestions/helps

Comment: my guess is that is 'hangs' when trying to extend the table (grabbing the next 1M of tablespace)  maybe try again with a larger initial extent.

Comment: I have tried to change it to 5MB, but no luck. thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: What happens when you do no logging, any change?

Comment: @Dennis, the same, no change. the thing confuses me is if the table is empty or only have a few records, uploading is OK.

Comment: Is this an exadata installation?

Comment: Then why did you set flash_cache and cell_flash_cache parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Trace the session that does the update on the server and look at the corresponding wait events.

A session can be traced by setting the 10046 event, while being connected to this session and before starting the load process.

```
alter session set events '10046 trace name context forever, level 12"
```

This will create trace files on the server that can be analyzed. The files are stored on the server, so your DBA needs to give you access to these files. Other options also exist like using ASH, but your DBA should be aware of this option anyway.

Comment: as DBA has purged the table, and the system works fine now on Production, I will try your sugguestion later on when the problem come back.